# image map hover effect css or jquery

Tags: image, hover, imagemap

i have made image map already, i want to highlight that particular section on hover using jquery or using css how do i do it?

I did not find any good article on this.

i have all the image map region working fine but the hover effect not wokring

i tried this css

```
.map{
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    height:475px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
}
#area2 {
    left:320px;
}
#area1:hover, #area2:hover ,#area3:hover,#area4:hover,#area5:hover{
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you a bit. Mapser is jquery plugin that helps you in such a kind of tasks http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html